# Low FPS on Linux compared to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, graphics-card, fps

I have recently installed Ubuntu as a dualboot to windows on my desktop computer (Just so you know it's the same computer).

Computer specs - i3 2130 (3.4GHz, 2 cores 4 threads), 8GiB DDR3 RAM, GTX 1050 2GiB

I have Minecraft installed on both systems. On windows it runs at anywhere from 200FPS to 300FPS. On Ubuntu, it runs anywhere from 20FPS to 30FPS.

I have [installed the nvidia drivers](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/) (version 390). I have checked the settings of the game, and they are similar to that of the windows version.

What might be causing this issue? Are there any known fixes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Nvidia drivers are one part of the puzzle, but it would seem that the Linux drivers do not implement the libraries to take maximum advantage of the card.

Comment: It would seem so... I'm just wondering _if_ there even is a fix, and if so what it is

Comment: @Jachdich - Are you sure your Linux install is configured to use the dGPU instead of the iGPU?  We are talking about a 900%+ difference.  Which would only be hardware.  The iGPU is extremely old (greater than 7 years old)

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I don't even know what that is! If you could link a document, or some way of checking which it is configured to use that'd be great

Comment: After a bit of googling - now I know what they stand for. I can't seem to find a way of checking which GPU it is using, but the video signal is coming from the dGPU if that's any help

Comment: Just because the video signal is connected to the GTX 1050 does not mean the software isn't using the Intel GPU.  Minecraft should indicate which GPU is being used.

Comment: @Ramhound Hmm... From the f3 screen it shows - "Display: 1920x1080 (nouveau) \n NV137 \n 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5" where "\n" is newline. This means nothing to me...

Comment: 300FPS sounds well beyond the display capabilities of most screens, I read a little about how it *might* reduce the *delay* in seeing a new frame from 16ms to 2ms - is minecraft the type of game where that extra 14ms would make a difference, or even be noticeable?

Comment: @Xen2050 I don't need the 300FPS, but I'd like more than 20. Sometimes delay decreases can be useful, but I am using Minecraft as more of a benchmark to see how the card is performing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't fix it :(. However I gave up on Ubuntu (the UI didn't really click with me) so I decided to try Mint. Once I had installed it, it automatically updated the drivers and everything worked very well.

Moral of the story: don't trust Ubuntu....

EDIT: actually Ubuntu is cool, I regret saying that actually. Moral of the story: Don't mess with Linux drivers.

Comment: "Don't mess with Linux drivers" is vague. Do you know what you did back then that was the culprit? What to avoid exactly? Any insight?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Unfortunately, I did not find the answer or what I did wrong. I will, however, edit the answer if I do ever find the issue/a solution. I agree that it is vague but it's the best I can do for now.